# Using Redemption to write message header

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

I have someone that is using MSAccess to send out emails and are using the Redemption library to help with putting together the email message.

However a new requirement has emerged where they will need to write some custom headers in the email message before sending.

The code is using RDO.Item to build the body of the email message.

I have seen some other suggestions where VBA and Outlook are used that after getting a MAPI session they have used .PropertyAccessor. methods to write items to the headers but I am unsure if this is possible via Redemption's MAPIOBJECT.

Is this something that the Redemption library is able to support?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is something like the following:

```
YouRDOMailObject.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/X-MyCustomHeader"] = "Some value";
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, I will give that a shot and let you know.

Comment: Here is the initialisation of the session and objects but when I attempt to use .Fields on RDOItem or RDOSent VBA comes back with "Invalid Use of Property"
 

    Set RDOSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession").  

    RDOSession.Logon. 

    Set RDOSent = RDOSession.GetDefaultFolder(Redemption.rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail). 

    Set RDOItem = RDOSent.Items.Add.

Comment: In VB, replace [] with ()

Comment: Hi Dmitry,

Thank you for your help. I can see the markings I was after once the email came through.

Thanks again